# Why would a 301 redirected RSS feed be appearing as an external link in Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console, wordpress, 301-redirect, links

We redirected our website over a year ago to a new domain. 301 is confirmed in place etc. All works fine.

However a couple of RSS feed URLs using the old domain have appeared in the external link tracker; when we visit these URLs they automatically redirect (as they should).

#### For example

- Search console for `https://www.newdomain.example`
- External link in search console: `https://www.olddomain.example/category/lorem/feed`

But when we visit that URL we are redirected to: `https://www.newdomain.example/category/lorem/feed`

How is this old and quite out-dated feed URL still appearing in Search Console? This seems like a WordPress issue since it's from a WordPress generated feed.